# Multibinding Visibility property of a RadButton on a RadGridViewRow

Tags: wpf, data-binding, radgridview

I need to be able to multibind the Visibility property of a RadButton placed on a RadGridView row to both the "IsSelected" property of the GridViewRow and a Public Property on the ViewModel (called "OtherValue" in this case). The purpose of this is to only show the [Delete] button on the selected row but also to be able to override this via custom code in the ViewModel based on certain business rules.

Any suggestions on the syntax for the binding for the multiconverter? I currently have the following:

```
              <telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <telerik:RadButton Width="70"
                                   Command="telerik:RadGridViewCommands.Delete"
                                   CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                   Content="Delete">

                  <telerik:RadButton.Visibility>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityMultiValueConverter}">
                      <Binding Path="IsSelected" />
                      <Binding Path="OtherValue" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                  </telerik:RadButton.Visibility>

                </telerik:RadButton>
              </DataTemplate>

            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
          </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

Comment: There's an example of binding to a GridViewRow.IsSelected provided by Telerik here: http://www.telerik.com/forums/isselected-property-of-a-gridrow .

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: I've never used any Telerik controls. This answer is likely to be right-*ish* rather than dead on the money, but should hopefully give you some notions:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <telerik:RadButton Width="70" Command="telerik:RadGridViewCommands.Delete" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Content="Delete">
        <telerik:RadButton.Visibility>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityMultiValueConverter}">
                <Binding ElementName="MyRadGridView", Path="Rows[0].IsSelected" />
                <Binding Path="OtherValue", RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadGridView}} />
            </MultiBinding>
         </telerik:RadButton.Visibility>
     </telerik:RadButton>
</DataTemplate>
```

You'll need to give your RadGridView a name which will replace MyRadGridView. As far as I can make out from  Telerik docs you should be able to bind a Row IsSelected property using the Row's index.

As your Button is inside a DataTemplate I think it's likely that you'll need to burrow back to your DataContext using RelativeSource/FindAncestor. If it doesn't bind against the RadGridView you can always try replacing that with Window/UserControl/whatever your RadGridView is housed in.